# How to stop duplicate data

Tags: elasticsearch

i am updating my documents in elasticsearch and adding new user, so just as an example suppose i am adding two new user to my field name "update_field". So now if i now add this two value in my field name "update_field", so if i try to insert that again it will not insert the data again or i mean it will not duplicate the data. How can i do that, can someone know how i can write a method to stop duplicate data for elasticsearch , i am working on PHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, simply change your script to this:

```
"script": "ctx._source.update_field = (ctx._source.update_field + new_value).unique();"
```

We're basically concatenating two lists in groovy and then with `unique()` we can remove all duplicates. Another way would be to cast the list as a `Set`, that would have the same effect.

Comment: Did you mean by ---
$script['script']= "ctx._source. update_field = (ctx._source. update_field + new_value).unique()";
apperently it is not working :)

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It was my mistake, i was doing it wrong. Thanks a lot for your great answer and help :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.